# Managing large forms - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I was reading about react forms, and I just can read about two ways of managing data in forms.

The first one - `refs`, putting refs in each data input:

```
class CustomTextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.focus = this.focus.bind(this);
  }

  focus() {
    // Explicitly focus the text input using the raw DOM API
    this.textInput.focus();
  }

  render() {
    // Use the `ref` callback to store a reference to the text input DOM
    // element in this.textInput.
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }} />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="Focus the text input"
          onClick={this.focus}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and the second one Controlled Forms, putting a handler for each data input:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Form from 'react-form-controlled';

export default class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      users: [{
        firstName: 'Zlatko'
      }, {
        firstName: 'Livia'
      }]
    };
  }

  onChange = (data) => {
    this.setState(data);
  }

  onSubmit = (data) => {
    alert(`Hi ${data.users[0].firstName}`);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Form
        value={this.state}
        onChange={this.onChange}
        onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
      >
        <fieldset name="users">
          <label>
            <input name="firstName" />
          </label>
        </fieldset>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

So, imagine you have a large form with a lot of data input, will you have to declare all the handler functions for each input in the form? (also, the total of bindings in the constructor)

Wouldn't it be convenient to just submit a just read `form.input1`, `form.input2`? I mean, somehing like this:

```
onSubmit(formValues){
    payload = [
        {'value1': formValues.input1 },
        {'value2': formValues.input2 },
        ...
        {'valueN': formValues.inputN },
    ]
}
```

without going to reading it from `state`?

I any case, is it and advantage to have a smart component with a lot of handlers for managing form values? or maybe the other approach, having a `refs` for each component in the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to check `redux` + `redux-form` combo. Managing form state with these modules is piece of case. You can have functional components without any local state or handlers.

Comment: Yeah I was reading about that. Another alternative is react redux forms, what about It?

Comment: We've chosen redux-form as it seems to be more mature. I worked for us like a charm. Including having various redux-forms on single screen and integration testing of such components.